# How do <% .. %> scriptlets work in webpack?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Full disclosure: I'm new to webpack and trying to figure out some of the "magic" that seems to happen behind the scenes.

In this page https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin there is some sample code like this:

```
<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

It seems that some kind of templating engine is running at build time to substitute the value of these variables. I've also seen other examples with `<% ... some js code %>`.

I just want to know how the templating works and where it is documented. Is it somehow built into webpack itself?  Is it an explicit loader? Is it part of htmlWebpackPlugin or can I use it with any loader? I've tried searching for the answer but searching for `<%=` in google is very hit-and-miss

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation has options that you can use for the template file](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates)

Take a look at it for all the options available

From the documentation:

> htmlWebpackPlugin: data specific to this plugin
>
> webpack: the webpack [stats](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/node.js-api#stats) object
>
> webpackConfig: the webpack configuration that was used for the compilation.
>
> compilation: the webpack [compilation](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation/) object

The `htmlWebpackPlugin` again has two options `files` and `options`. If you want to send any user defined values use the `htmlWebpackPlugin.options`